# Develop tweaks to facebook like app

Tags: facebook, html, tampermonkey, tweak

I am doing a hobby project by implementing a phd paper on 'The privacy issues on facebook' and it suggests some tweaks to the existing facebook remove tag option like including an additional setting like '**Review posts in which you are tagged in before the audience of the post see in their News feed**'. So the point being I am required to **tweak facebook webpages** to include these options.

So can someone give me ideas on ways to achieve it ?

My groundwork includes checking out tamper monkey to dynamically run user scripts on loading

Can this be achieved with tamper monkey or is there any developed mock facebook apps on github which I can make use of ?

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Tampermonkey can change what's displayed *to you*, can mashup multiple web pages, and can automate certain tasks.  It cannot change how a site operates on the back end -- which sounds like what you're after.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have achieved it using TamperMonkey by executing scripts corresponding to the tweaks likewise suggested in one of the comments

Here is a project which contains tamper monkey scripts to perform few tweaks corresponding to facebook page

https://github.com/aarishramesh/facebook-privacy

It contains scripts for the following

- Display picture privacy
- Profile visits
- Review posts in which you are tagged in before the audience of the post sees the post in their feed